# FactoryGirl + Ancestry with two level deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, ancestry

Basically:

- I have a `Structure` model that has many `Subjects`.
- Each subject has a parent and it can be 2-levels deep.
- A `Structure` has to have one Subject at_depth 0 and one Subject at_depth 2.

The problem:

- I can't figure out how to build my Subject Factory and how to make the association in the Structure Factory.

I'm on Rails 4, factory_girl_rails 4.2.1 and Ruby 2.0.0

Here is what I tried for the subject factory:

```
factory :subject_grand_parent do |f|
  name Forgery(:name).company_name

  factory :subject_parent do |s|
    f.parent { Factory.create(:subject_grand_parent) }

    factory :subject do |s|
      f.parent { Factory.create(:subject_parent) }
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't define parent two times.

And in the `Structure` factory I'm not sure how to define multiple subjects for my association. Here
what I have now:

```
factory :structure do
  subjects {|structure| [structure.association(:subject)] }
  ...
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using after(:build) blocks ?

Comment: How could not think of that! That worked. But then how do I assign multiple subjects to my structure factory?

Comment: after(:build) do |structure|  
  2.times { structure.subject << build(:subject, structure: structure) }
end

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this seems to work:

`Subject` Factory:

factory :subject do
    name Forgery(:name).company_name

```
factory :subject_children do
  name Forgery(:name).company_name + ' child'

  after :build do |subject|
    subject_grand_parent   = Subject.create(name: Forgery(:name).company_name)
    subject_parent         = subject_grand_parent.children.create(name: Forgery(:name).company_name)
    subject.parent         = subject_parent
    subject.ancestry_depth = 2
  end
end
```

end

`Structure` Factory:

```
after(:build) do |structure|
  structure.subjects << FactoryGirl.build(:subject)
  structure.subjects << FactoryGirl.build(:subject_children)
end
```